# json android: How to read the online json format

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am new to android. I have a url which only has the json format. Suppose the url is- http://www.example.com/filter... This url contains only json format data. Take for example this link contains following material: - [ {u:"user",s:"male" image:"hello.jpg"}] 
The link contains only the above data. Now, I want to test the connection in my android i.e.whether i am able to connect to the values of parameter u. I created a http client and tried to parse the json format. The program but does not display anything.. Here's what i did

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/filter");

    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

byte [] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
        while (in.read(buffer) != -1);
        String jsontext = new String(buffer);
        JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(i);
            if(post.getString("u")=="driver")
            {
            x="Success";
            }
        }

        txtResult.setText(x); // x is string
    }
```

I just want to test my connection. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Keys have to be quoted:

```
[{"u": "user", "s": "male", "image": "hello.jpg"}]
```

It might be valid JavaScript, but it's not valid JSON.

You might also want to look in logcat and post any exceptions that occur (I'm sure you get an invalid JSON exception somewhere).

Comment: u know what.. when i copy the json format,( the same i posted above, ) into a raw file and then check the connection it runs fine.. maybe the format is not invalid.. can u tell me how to read the format widout creating a raw file!?

Comment: The JSON **is** invalid, you can check at jsonlint.com. As for reading data from the network, there are plenty of tutorials on the Internet for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse "u" from your response `{u:"user",s:"male", image:"hello.jpg"}` then your code seems fine except the string comparison that you have implemented:

Wrong:

```
if(post.getString("u")=="driver")
 {
            x="Success";
 }
```

True:

```
if(post.getString("u").eqaulIgnoreCase("driver"))
{
   x="success"
}
```

Comment: Your exact json has a mistake, there's no comma after "male". It should be `{u:"user",s:"male",image:"hello.jpg"}`